# get product specific data and update variable and single products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I am trying to get all products from WooCommerce, which I will use later for update with some json data that already have.

i tried `wc_get_products` and `get_post`, but still dont understand how get the data.

For the products i need data something like this:

```
[
{
id: 1999,
name: black spinner
SKU: ABC-1
    variation data{
    atribute name: ref
    atribute value:RN20S1
    atribute price: $200
    }
}
{
id: 2194,
name: white spinner
SKU: ABC-2
    variation data{
    atribute name: ref
    atribute value:RN20S2
    atribute price: $210
    }
}
....
]
```

Why i need the data like this?

the json data from other database only have *atribute value* and *atribute price*, and that's the data I need to update

i think this can be done with $wpdb, but don't know how to build the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all products using the following function:

```
<?php $array = WC_API_Products::get_products( $fields, $type, $filter, $page ); ?>
```

Note that all parameters are optional. If I'm not wrong, leaving the parameters blank should get you every product.

After that you can loop through all products and get the desired informations with the specific methods. For the name(product title) for example it could look like this:

```
<?php foreach ( $array as $currentProduct ){ $currentProduct->get_name(); } ?'
```

Comment: Hi!
i'll try, bit i think this only get me basic info, no variable nor other values like attributes
Do you know where i can check the specific methods?

Comment: Here is a list with all specific methods to the product object.  [Click](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-product-info-title-sku-desc-product-object/). As you will see, there is a method to get all variations: "get_children()". Hope this helps.